# Что обозначает Int.Parse?

Tags: c#

Что обозначает Int.Parse?

```
result = int.Parse(textBox.Text) + 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно MSDN [Int32.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.int32.parse.aspx):

> Преобразует строковое представление числа в эквивалентное 32-битовое знаковое целое число.

То есть была строка '12345', а стало число 12345. Аналогично для Int16 и Int64.

Answer (score 0):

Статический метод, который преобразует переменную типа строка в целое число.